# Ocultar css en iframe si el texto contiene una palabra específica

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, javascript-objeto

tengo un reto que me está costando solucionar.

Necesito ocultar un div que carga un elemento de JavaScript en un iframe. El div para ocultar debe contener el texto "Siguiente"

Ejemplo:

```
<div class="alignNext">
<div class="inlineBlock nextAlign" elname="next"><button class="fmSmtButton next_previous navWrapper" type="button" elname="next" onclick="gotoNextPage(this);">
<em> Siguiente </em>
</button></div></div>
```

He probado con:

```
<script>
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".alignNext");
Array.from(divs).forEach(function(div) {
  if (div.textContent.indexOf("Siguiente") >= 0 ) {
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
});
</script>
```

Pero no funciona con el iframe.

El código del iframe es:

```
<div id="zf_div_IsBaC6OI1EsmTbQpQNijKuyc2G6W7voKPIu077b1tZY"></div><script type="text/javascript">(function() {
try{
var f = document.createElement("iframe");   
f.src = 'https://forms.zohopublic.eu/how/form/SACMDPAGINADO/formperma/IsBaC6OI1EsmTbQpQNijKuyc2G6W7voKPIu077b1tZY?zf_rszfm=1';
f.style.border="none";                                           
f.style.height="278px";
f.style.width="90%";
f.style.transition="all 0.5s ease";// No I18N
var d = document.getElementById("zf_div_IsBaC6OI1EsmTbQpQNijKuyc2G6W7voKPIu077b1tZY");
d.appendChild(f);
window.addEventListener('message', function (){
var zf_ifrm_data = event.data.split("|");
var zf_perma = zf_ifrm_data[0];
var zf_ifrm_ht_nw = ( parseInt(zf_ifrm_data[1], 10) + 15 ) + "px";
var iframe = document.getElementById("zf_div_IsBaC6OI1EsmTbQpQNijKuyc2G6W7voKPIu077b1tZY").getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
if ( (iframe.src).indexOf('formperma') > 0 && (iframe.src).indexOf(zf_perma) > 0 ) {
var prevIframeHeight = iframe.style.height;
if ( prevIframeHeight != zf_ifrm_ht_nw ) {
iframe.style.height = zf_ifrm_ht_nw;
}   
}
}, false);
}catch(e){}
})();</script>
```

He dejado el código en Codepen por si esto sirve de ayuda para explicar mejor lo que quiero conseguir:
https://codepen.io/dlopezros/pen/GRjrgwQ

gracias por vuestra ayuda.